Group representation of a division ring without zero multiplication
It seems like we can construct a group from a division ring that preserves the algebraic structure except for multiplications by zero.
Assuming that this is correct (see derivation below), I was wondering:

Is there a name for this?
Is it useful in any way? For mathematics, computation, etc.


Suppose we have a division ring $(R,+,\cdot)$, with identity $\mathbf{0}$, unity $\mathbf{1}$, additive inverse of $x$ denoted as $-x$, and multiplicative inverse denoted as $x^{-1}$.
Define the elements of group $(G,\circ)$ as $\{f=[a_f,b_f], a_f\in R\setminus\mathbf{0},b_f\in R\}$.
The idea is that $f$ is a function $R\rightarrow R$ where $f(x):=a_f x + b_f$; the goal is to define $\circ:G\times G\rightarrow G$ such that we have function composition. We can do this by defining $f\circ g:=[a_f a_g,a_f b_g + b_f]$, i.e., $a_f(a_g x + b_g) + b_f=a_f a_g x + a_f b_g + b_f$.
The intuition is that we can compose any number of additions, subtractions, multiplications, and divisions and then apply them later. Sort of like computing bank account transactions and interest over time without knowing the starting balance.

Mutiplication by $x\neq\mathbf{0}$ would be $[x,\mathbf{0}]$.
Division by $x\neq\mathbf{0}$ would be $[x^{-1},\mathbf{0}]$.
Addition of $x$ would be $[\mathbf{1},x]$.
Subtraction of $x$ would be $[\mathbf{1},-x]$.


Proof that this is a group:

$[a,b]\circ[c,d]=[ac,ad+b]\in G$ because $ac\in R\setminus\mathbf{0}$ and $ad+b\in R$.

The identity for this group is $e:=[\mathbf{1},\mathbf{0}]$.

$[a,b]\circ[\mathbf{1},\mathbf{0}]=[a\mathbf{1},a\mathbf{0}+b]=[a,b]$
$[\mathbf{1},\mathbf{0}]\circ[a,b]=[\mathbf{1}a,\mathbf{1}b+\mathbf{0}]=[a,b]$


The inverse of $[a,b]$ can be defined as $[a^{-1},a^{-1}(-b)]$.

$[a,b]\circ[a^{-1},a^{-1}(-b)]=[aa^{-1},a(a^{-1}(-b))+b]=[\mathbf{1},\mathbf{0}]=e$
$[a^{-1},a^{-1}(-b)]\circ[a,b]=[a^{-1}a,a^{-1}b+a^{-1}(-b)]=[\mathbf{1},\mathbf{0}]=e$ (using distributive property of $R$)


Lastly, $\circ$ is associative.

$([a,b]\circ[c,d])\circ[e,f]=[ac,ad+b]\circ[e,f]=[(ac)e,(ac)f+(ad+b)]=[ace,acf+ad+b]$
$[a,b]\circ([c,d]\circ[e,f])=[a,b]\circ[ce,cf+d]=[a(ce),a(cf+d)+b]=[ace,acf+ad+b]$




Note that this doesn't depend on addition in $R$ being commutative, even though it's still required by definition of a ring.
I also think we could do this with a group $V$ and a group $M$ whose elements are endomorphisms of $V$ that distribute, with the derived group having elements in $M\times V$, and use the mostly same construction and proof above. (Proving closedness would be slightly more complicated.)

Isn’t this the affine group of the ring?  Or awfully close to it.

Also, you do need the addition in the ring to be commutative so that your operation is closed.

Yeah, I was just thinking that it was similar to affine transformations. $R$ doesn't need to operate on a vector space, though.

I don't think the derivation relies on commutativity of addition. All multiplication is on the left and all addition is on the right, and we never need to reorder addition.

Actually, I don't think it would be an affine group because $a$ and $b$ are both in $R$, vs. $b$ coming from a vector space that $R$ operates on. Maybe the last part about $V\times M$ would be a generalization of an affine group, though.
